# regenerate-makefiles.sh generates libtoolize linking error when compiling IRSTLM

Tags: cygwin, libtool, mt

I'm having trouble getting IRSTLM to compile, due to an apparent problem linking to the ltmain.sh file in the libtool directories. I'm using Cygwin, by the way.

```
cook@mt-g66 /cygdrive/c/irstlm/trunk
$ ./regenerate-makefiles.sh
Calling /usr/bin/libtoolize
libtoolize: putting auxiliary files in '../..'.
libtoolize:   error: linking '/usr/share/libtool/build-aux/ltmain.sh' to '../../' failed
libtoolize failed
```

Could someone please point me in the right direction as to how to overcome this? I've double-checked that Cygwin installed libtool, but I'm very new to Cygwin, so there may be a step that I've overlooked. I have little experience of compiling applications generally, but have been unable to locate an installer version of IRSTLM.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

first of all you need to install the dependencies ...thats why you got something like this `ibtoolize:   error: linking '/usr/share/libtool/build-aux/ltmain.sh' to '../../' failed
libtoolize failed`

so follow the steps one by one ...

1. Get the source from here http://sourceforge.net/projects/irstlm/
2. Installing some dependencies

   `sudo apt-get install build-essential
   sudo apt-get install automake
   sudo apt-get install libtool
   sudo apt-get install zlib1g-dev`
3. Extracting files

   `sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/src/irstlm
   sudo chown username /usr/local/src/irstlm
   tar -xvzf irstlm.tgz -C /usr/local/src/irstlm`
4. Compiling

   `sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/lib/irstlm 
   sudo chown username /usr/local/lib/irstlm
   ./regenerate-makefiles.sh
   ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/lib/irstlm --enable-caching
   make -j 4`
5. Installing

   `make -j 4 install`

good luck ..!

Comment: Thank you for the advice. There's one small glitch, and that's that sudo does not work in Cygwin. Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: i never tried cygwin. but i thing you can try :- [link](http://superuser.com/questions/304541/how-to-install-new-packages-on-cygwin).

Comment: It seems to have worked, by prefixing apt-get with runas instead of sudo. Elsewhere, it worked when I dispensed with suno.

Answer (score 1):

there's actually another situation that can cause the libtoolize that was not really addressed here. Permission and access issues. Consider the following situation: you're in virtualbox and trying to run libtoolize out of a VBox Shared folder, you will get this error. Move the project within the machine, error is gone.